# Rails, Heroku and assets without the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm actually not sure if this is a rails thing or a heroku thing but I need to know how I can serve up static assets without the asset pipleline. I do want to use the asset pipeline for most of my javascript but I have some files that I want to exclude and serve at my own choosing. I am new to Rails and Heroku so I am a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I create a folder in assets/javascript/exclusive or something like that and I make sure it is Not included in application.js.  Then go to config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += ['exclusive/*']
```

Now your javascript still takes advantage of the asset pipeline without having to be on the master javascript file.

Then in the view you want your javascript:

```
<%- content_for :javascript do -%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'exclusive/something' %>
<%- end -%>
```

Make sure that you add
`<%= yield :javascript %>` somewhere in you layout file (application.html.erb) after the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` so that any dependencies such as jQuery that the exclusive javascript depends on are loaded first.